# foreach文で取得した変数を、さらに一つの配列にまとめたい

Tags: php, laravel, csv

以下のような、質問と回答が3セットで一行を成す、10行分のCSVファイルがあります。

```
質問1||回答1||質問2||回答2||質問3||回答3
```

このCSVファイルの回答をPHP(Laravel)で集計するために、以下のような操作を行おうと試みています。

①このCSVファイルを1行ずつインポートし、それぞれの行のn列目の値をforeach文で取得

②取得した、1行目〜10行目までのn列目の値をさらに一つの配列に直す。
全ての行のn列目の値をまとめた配列から、この配列全体の要素数と、重複している要素の数を取得する。

この操作を行うために、以下のようなコードを書いておりますが、②の一つの配列にまとめなおすコードが分かりません。

$answer1から$answer3までそれぞれ、foreach文をネストにして配列を作るのだとしても、どういったコードを書けばいいのか苦悩しております。

コードが汚く恐縮ですが、ご教授いただけますようお願いいたします。

```
public function store(Request $request){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');

    $uploaded_file = $request->file('file');

    $file_path = $request->file('file')->path($uploaded_file);

    $file = new \SplFileObject($file_path);

    $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

    $row_count = 1;

    foreach ($file as $row)
    {
        // 1行目のヘッダーは取り込まない
        if ($row_count > 1)
        {
            //各値を取得する
            $id = mb_convert_encoding($row[0],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $question1 = mb_convert_encoding($row[1], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $answer1 = mb_convert_encoding($row[2],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $question2 = mb_convert_encoding($row[3] "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $answer2 = mb_convert_encoding($row[4], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $question3 = mb_convert_encoding($row[5], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $answer3 = mb_convert_encoding($row[6], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

        }
        $row_count++;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

新しい配列に入れる時は 以下のコードで（とりあえず全て詰めて見ました）　必要なら配列を複数作成してください。
$out_arr[] = array($id,$question1,$answer1,$question2,$answer2,$question3,$answer3);

正しく理解するには [PHP の配列](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.types.array.php)

*以下 コード例*

```
$out_arr = array();//初期化
foreach ($file as $row)
{
    // 1行目のヘッダーは取り込まない
    if ($row_count > 1)
    {
        //各値を取得する
        $id = mb_convert_encoding($row[0],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

        $question1 = mb_convert_encoding($row[1], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

        $answer1 = mb_convert_encoding($row[2],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

        $question2 = mb_convert_encoding($row[3],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $answer2 = mb_convert_encoding($row[4], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $question3 = mb_convert_encoding($row[5], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $answer3 = mb_convert_encoding($row[6], "UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));
        $out_arr[] = array($id,$question1,$answer1,$question2,$answer2,$question3,$answer3);//例１
//      $out_arr[$row_count] = [$id,$question1,$answer1,$question2,$answer2,$question3,$answer3];//例２お好きなように
//      $out_arr[] = array($id,'$question1'=>$answer1,'$question2'=>$answer2,'$question3'=>$answer3);//例3お好きなように
        }
    $row_count++;

}
//print_r($out_arr);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。考えすぎておりましたが、こんなにシンプルな問題とは思いませんでした。こちらで、配列として取得できました。